# PHP, MySQL Insert Into table in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm pretty new to MySQL and PHP, and I had a little problem with Inserting into table.

- I have build 'setup.php' that have all MySQL codes but I didn't know how to included correctly to 'index.php'.
- I tried to separate the code as the following, but still didn't work. I don't know what's the problem here, is it the code itself? or the way i included it? Please help me fix it.

index.php, The code is right after body element.

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) &&
isset($_POST['email']) &&
isset($_POST['place']) &&
isset($_POST['level'])) {

include "setup.php";

$name =      sanitizeString($_POST['name']);
$email =     sanitizeString($_POST['email']);
$place =   sanitizeString($_POST['place']);
$level =     sanitizeString($_POST['level']);

$query = "INSERT INTO customers VALUES('$name', '$email', '$place', '$level')";
queryMysql($query);

}
```

setup.php

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'applicants';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';

mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

function createTable($name, $query) {
    if (tableExists($name)) {
        echo "Table $name already exists";
    }
    else {
        queryMysql("CREATE TABLE $name($query)");
    }
}

function tableExists($name) {
    $result = queryMysql("SHOW TABLES LIKE $name");
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}

function queryMysql($query) {
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    return $result;
}

createTable('customers',
            'name VARCHAR(16),
            email VARCHAR(16),
            place VARCHAR(16),
            level VARCHAR(16)');
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get errors? What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: Nothing get inserted in table. However, I don't get any error. What is wrong?

Comment: Use PDO, it's a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Using PDO is a better approach:

```
function validatePost($post) {
    return (isset($post['name']) &&
        isset($post['email']) &&
        isset($post['place']) &&
        isset($post['level']));
}

function createTable(PDO $pdo, $name, $query) {
    if (tableExists($pdo, $name)) {
        throw new Exception("Table already exists");
    }
    $pdo->query("CREATE TABLE $name($query)");
}

function tableExists(PDO $pdo, $name) {
    $result = $pdo->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE $name");
    return count($result->fetchAll());
}

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbname = 'applicants';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'root';

validatePost($_POST);
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    createTable($pdo, "customers",
        "name VARCHAR(16),
         email VARCHAR(16),
         place VARCHAR(16),
         level VARCHAR(16)");

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO `customers` (`name`, `email`, `place`, `level`) VALUES(:name, :email, :place, :level)");
    $stmt->bindParam(":name", $_POST["name"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":email", $_POST["email"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":place", $_POST["place"]);
    $stmt->bindParam(":level", $_POST["level"]);
    $stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "There was an error regarding the Database: " . $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error! " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

You have a PDO object which acts as the connection, it is then passed around the functions in order to operate.

#### Points

- PDO supports prepared statements, which removes the need to sanitize (the prepared statement does it for you!)
- When inserting, it's considered a good practice to expicitely declare which column gets what, I've assumed the names of your columns, but you should change them if they don't match.
- Don't echo, throw Exceptions. Throwing an exception allows you to deal with problems and errors in your code much more efficiently and easily. You throw an exception and catch it where it may occur. An uncaught (`catch`ed) exception will terminate the script.

Comment: "...removes the need to "sanitize" yet *adds the need to bind.* What's the gain then? ;-)

Comment: Well, you can bind a parameter once, then change the parameter and execute again, without the need to rebind/resanitize.

Comment: err, I am afraid you are confusing something :) I am curious, have you used such a feature yourself?

Comment: Of course, when inserting a mass of lines, the use of transactions and parameter binding is very handy, and very efficient.

Comment: Ah, yes. when you bind a variable, not value, it seems you don't have to rebind them. My bad. However, I don't see much benefit here, as such a bulk insert is surely being done in a loop, so, no much difference from escaping.

Comment: Yes, only you'll need to sanitize on each iteration, rather than doing it once and loop throw the variables. Anyway, this isn't the place, if you want, create a chat room and invite me, I'll be happy to discuss it with you :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7580/discussion-between-col-shrapnel-and-truth)

Comment: Thank you, I have learned a lot. However, I got an error message and I don't know what it means: There was an error regarding the Database: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'customers' at line 1

Answer (score -1):

In index.php, the query should be

```
mysql_query($query)
```

not queryMysql.

Plus, make sure you are inserting every field in the database. If you have auto increment field or field which you aren't using, use this syntax

```
INSERT INTO products (column 1, column 2) VALUES (value1, value2)
```

p.s. Change your all  queryMysql to mysql_query(). I believe there's no function like queryMysql (i have stopped using this mysql_* functions long ago so i could be wrong but about mysql_query() i am sure that it'l work).

Comment: Still nothing get insert into table. queryMysql is a function I coded in setup.php! I thought it would work?

Comment: There are lots of issues with your codes. 

Turn on error reporting by 

    error_reporting(-1);

at the begining of your script. And update the script after you changed. And please change all queryMysql to mysql_query(). 

Plus show us from where the POST variables are coming. Are index and name of the inputs same?